Nginx doesn't seem to recognize index.html
I just bought VPS on Hostinger and i'm trying to deploy my app, my NodeJS server is working fine at ***, I have my ReactJS build folder in root /bushnaq/client/dist which contains index.html, but when i visit my domain at bushnaq.group, it says 404 not found, which is the fallback, as I understand, nginx doesn't recognize the path root /bushnaq/client/dist
bushnaq.group.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bushnaq.group;

    location / {
        root /bushnaq/client/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

}

index.js
import express from "express";
import dbConnection from "./dbConnection.js";
import routes from "./routes.js";
import cors from "cors";
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: "https://ashoshari.github.io/bushnaq-group/" }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const host = process.env.HOST || "0.0.0.0";

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
app.use("/api", routes);
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";
  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    message: err.message,
  });
});

// If database is connected successfully, then run the server

dbConnection
  .getConnection()
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port, host, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Failed to connect to the database: ${err.message}`);
  });



I cannot reproduce this issue despite of a dozen misconfigurations tried. What version of nginx do you use?

@DmitryMeyer nginx version: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)

Still cannot reproduce. I started Ubuntu 24.04 in Docker container, install nginx, the same version 1.24.0, copied your configuration as /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, and get 404 if the root directory does not exist or 403 if the root directory exists, but index.html does not, and 200 if both exist. Try to remove $uri/ from the try_files list (the second argument, with traling slash one), it should fix, but I have no idea why it doesn't work as is.

@DmitryMeyer I don't think the problem is caused by Nginx misconfugration, maybe because I transferred the domain to hostinger something went wrong or needs extra configuration

btw, http://bushnaq.group/index.html also returns 404. This should work 100%, there is no place for "internal redirection cycle"

@DmitryMeyer the problem was related to permissions, but now solved after changing permissions for the dist folder and its parents up to the root directory

The problem was related to permissions, the nginx user (usually www-data) didn't has permissions to access the dist directory, so i had to change permissions for the project directory
